# DOMPDF auto width and height

Tags: php, dom, cakephp-1.3, dompdf

Is there anyway i can make the width and height of the pdf into auto so that the size of the paper will depend on its content? Thank you! Cheers!

Comment: that's backwards, as in the print world your printer usually has access to one size of paper.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, and I doubt any PDF generator has such a feature.